# Can I export mailbox contents from an Exchange 2007 server if I install Outlook 2010 x64 on the same server?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, outlook, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

As per [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb266964%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx), in order to export mailbox contents from Exchange 2007, you need to use a 32-bit computer with the following software installed:

- Exchange 2007 management tools
- Outlook 2003 or Outlook 2007

The 32-bit requirement comes from Outlook, which until the 2010 release wasn't available as a 64-bit application, so it wasn't able to interact with x64 Exchange management tools.

However, Outlook 2010 ***has*** a 64-bit version; thus, my question: if I install Outloook 2010 x64 on an Exchange 2007 (x64) server, will I be able to directly export mailbox contents from there, without the need to deploy a 32-bit computer only for this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Massimo,

Unless something has changed over the years with some new patch or hotfix to 2007, and I don't think it has, it still won't work.  The error will still kick out because it looks at the OS and not the app, looking for a 32bit OS itself.  I recall having to go with a 3rd party program because of this issue in the past.

UPDATE:  I found this: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/d2c41018-3dc3-44b8-b972-c74c72bdf07d/exch-2007-sp2-x64-exportmailbox-possible-w-outlook-2010-x64 and it appears to confirm the same issue still holds true:

> I confirm, it doesn't work, I try to do it but no success...
>
> When you run the command:
>
> Export-Mailbox -Identity rfederer -PSTFolderPath E:\PST
>
> you obtain:
>
> You are running on a 64-bit computer. To export to or import from a
>   .pst file, you must be running a 32-bit computer that has Outlook 2003
>   SP2 or later installed. At line:1 char:1

Comment: Agreed: it doesn't work :(